# Adding total/overall row using tbl_uvregression in gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

I would like to add a total row in my table. I am using the tbl_uvregression() to make a specific table summarizing univariable analysis using a Poisson model. The overall row will indicate the total events and total number of time at risk for the sample.
Below is my dataset and code

```
df = tibble(
  study_arm = c("C", "T", "C", "T", "C", "T", "C", "T"),
  events = c(3,4,12,6,7, 8,9,10),
  time_at_risk = c(100,200,400,200,300,100,500,500)
)
```

```
library(gtsummary)

df %>% 
  tbl_uvregression(y= events,
                   method = glm,
                   formula = "{y} ~ {x} + offset(log(time_at_risk))",
                    method.args = list(family = poisson(link = log)),
                   exponentiate = TRUE,
                    include= -time_at_risk,
                   hide_n = TRUE,
                   pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to get followup time in the table...it's not a new row, however.

```r
library(gtsummary)

df <-
  dplyr::tibble(
    study_arm = c("C", "T", "C", "T", "C", "T", "C", "T"),
    events = c(3,4,12,6,7, 8,9,10),
    time_at_risk = c(100,200,400,200,300,100,500,500)
  )

tbl <-
  df %>% 
  tbl_uvregression(
    y= events,
    method = glm,
    formula = "{y} ~ {x} + offset(log(time_at_risk))",
    method.args = list(family = poisson(link = log)),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    include= -time_at_risk,
    hide_n = TRUE,
    pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 3)
  ) %>%
  modify_header(exposure = "**Total Exposure Time**")

tbl %>% as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **Total Exposure Time** | **IRR** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| study_arm |  |  |  |  |
| C | 1,300 | — | — |  |
| T | 1,000 | 1.17 | 0.70, 1.96 | 0.538 |

```r
# view all items already saved in the results table
tbl$table_body
#> # A tibble: 3 × 29
#>   tbl_id1 variable  var_label var_type   reference_row row_type header_row N_obs
#>     <int> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>      <lgl>         <chr>    <lgl>      <dbl>
#> 1       1 study_arm study_arm dichotomo… NA            label    TRUE           8
#> 2       1 study_arm study_arm dichotomo… TRUE          level    FALSE          8
#> 3       1 study_arm study_arm dichotomo… FALSE         level    FALSE          8
#> # ℹ 21 more variables: N_event <dbl>, N <dbl>, coefficients_type <chr>,
#> #   coefficients_label <chr>, label <chr>, term <chr>, var_class <chr>,
#> #   var_nlevels <int>, contrasts <chr>, contrasts_type <chr>, n_obs <dbl>,
#> #   n_event <dbl>, exposure <dbl>, estimate <dbl>, std.error <dbl>,
#> #   statistic <dbl>, nevent <dbl>, conf.low <dbl>, conf.high <dbl>, ci <chr>,
#> #   p.value <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>